# Snakemake: dependencies which are not input

Tags: snakemake

I'd like to know if there is a way in Snakemake to define a dependency which is actually not an input file.
What I mean by that is that there are programs that expect some files to exists while there are not provided on the command line.

Let's consider `bwa` as an example.
This is a rule from [Johannes Köster mapping rules](https://bitbucket.org/johanneskoester/snakemake-workflows/src/fa47806ee1dabda8f1ac77877bc831d1f2c8b9f9/bio/ngs/rules/mapping/?at=master):

```
rule bwa_mem_map:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config["references"][wildcards.reference],
        lambda wildcards: config["units"][wildcards.unit]
    output:
        "mapping/{reference}/units/{unit}.bam"
    params:
        sample=lambda wildcards: UNIT_TO_SAMPLE[wildcards.unit],
        custom=config.get("params_bwa_mem", "")
    log:
        "mapping/log/{reference}/{unit}.log"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        "bwa mem {params.custom} "
        r"-R '@RG\tID:{wildcards.unit}\t"
        "SM:{params.sample}\tPL:{config[platform]}' "
        "-t {threads} {input}  2> {log} "
        "| samtools view -Sbh - > {output}"
```

Here, bwa expect that the genome index file exists while it is not a command-line argument (the path to the index file is deduced from the genome path).

Is there a way to tell Snakemake that the index file is a dependency, and Snakemake will look in its rule if he knows how to generate this file ?

I suppose you could still rewrite your rule inputs as:

```
rule bwa_mem_map:
    input:
        genome=lambda wildcards: config["references"][wildcards.reference],
        fastq=lambda wildcards: config["units"][wildcards.unit]
        index=foo.idx
```

And adapt the rule `run` part consequently.
Is it the best solution?

Thanks in advance.
Benoist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way snakemake handles dependencies between rules is through files, so I'd say you are doing it correctly when you put the index file explicitly as an `input` for your mapping rule, even though this file does not appear in the mapping command.

For what its worth, I do the same for bam index files, which are an implicit dependency for some tools: I put both the sorted bam file and its index as `input`, but only use the bam file in the `shell` or `run` part. And I have a rule generating both having the two files as `output`.

`input` and `output` files do not need to appear in `shell` / `run` parts of a rule.